# Angular 2 HTTP Request Issue

Tags: express, angular, typescript

Really hoping someone can help me.

What I am trying to do: Call a REST API for a json and resolve a Angular 2 promise.

**ServerAPI running Node.js/ExpressJS/Lodash**

Server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var data = require('./data.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
var cors = require('cors');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());


app.get('/GetData', function (req, resp) {

if (req.query.search != null) {

    var result = _.find(data, function (o) {
        return o.value === req.query.search.toLowerCase().trim()
    });

    return resp.send(result)

} 

});

    app.listen(1337, function () {
    console.log('Listening at Port 1337'); 
});
```

Ran as tested http://localhost:1337/GetData?search=colorado and returns a vaild json object.

**ClientAPI**

Service file calling HTTP request:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Config} from "../config";
import {SearchResult} from "../models/search-result.model";
import {MockSearchData} from "../mock/mock-search-results";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class ApiDataService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    public     performSearchRequest(searchTerm:string,queryType:string):Promise<SearchResult[]>     {
    return new Promise<SearchResult[]>((resolve, reject) => {

        let url = Config.apiBaseUrl + Config.searchApi;
        url += "?search=" + searchTerm;

        console.log("Your query to be: " + url);

        if (searchTerm != "") {

            if (queryType == 'mock') {

                resolve(MockSearchData);


            } else if (queryType == 'api') {

                let data = [];

                this.http.get(url)
                    .map(resp => resp.json())
                    .subscribe(getData => data = getData);

                resolve(data);

            } else {

                reject("No query type found.");

            }

        } else {

            reject("Please enter a search term.");

        };

    });
}
}
```

The resolve of the mock data which is a local json file within the ClientAPI works perfectly. I need to get the if function for the api query type to work.

The Angular app starts with no issue and runs the http.get without error. I checked the network tab under the dev tools and can see that a HTTP request was done and returns its response is the valid JSON object I want resolved e.g there is data being returned. Yet the table i am resolving this into is blank.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG!

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs here:

```
this.http.get(url)
   .map(resp => resp.json())
   .subscribe(getData => data = getData);

resolve(data);
```

You subscribe to the observable, but it isn’t “resolved” yet when you call `resolve` directly afterwards. That means you’re really just calling `resolve([])`.

Instead, do something like this:

```
this.http.get()./*...*/.subscribe(result => resolve(result));
```

You also might want to look into the [`toPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) method on Observables as well as the way to construct a resolved promise directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am however getting the same results.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint in either the `map` or the `subscribe` callback methods?

Comment: It seems though the format that it is return as it not the same as the mock data when i console log the results. Added console error in subscribe callback method and got the following: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Well that’s another, separate issue, then. Just make sure you didn’t break the callback by putting `console.log` inside. You should really leave the code as is and add a break point in your browser’s Javascript debugger.